# Multi-Index Dataframes are missing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two dataframes df2, with the payment statistics (that have the probability of the client pay a certain debt) and df3 with new clients data.

I want to calculate the estimate amout that a client would pay by estimate. Ex: If a client is from Lisbon , have Visa and Colateral, it have 0.333333 change of paying 0% of debt, 0.3333% change of paying ]0-25%] of debt and 0,3333% of paying ]0,75-1]% of the debt. So if this client have a debt of 100, the expected value whould be from

[(0,33 * 0 * 100)+(0 * 0 * 100)+(0,33 * 0,75 * 100] to [(0,33 * 0 * 100 + 0,33 * 0,25 * 100+0,33 * 1 * 100).

So this client would pay from 24,75€ to 41,25€ as the following code does:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Lisbon','Lisbon','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Lisbon','Lisbon','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo'], 
    'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Master Card','Master Card','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Master Card','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Master Card'],
    'Colateral':['Yes','No','Yes','No','No','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','No','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','No','No'],
    'Client Number':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],
    'DebtPaid':[0.8,0.1,0.5,0.30,0,0.2,0.4,1,0.60,1,0.5,0.2,0,0.3,0,0,0.2,0,0.1,0.70,0.5,0.1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df2=df.groupby(['City','Card','Colateral'])['DebtPaid'].\
          value_counts(bins=[-0.001,0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.001,2],normalize=True)

d = {'City': ['Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Lisbon','Lisbon','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo','Tokyo','Lisbon','Lisbon','Lisbon','Tokyo','Lisbon','Tokyo'], 
    'Card': ['Visa','Visa','Master Card','Master Card','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Master Card','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Visa','Master Card','Visa','Master Card'],
    'Colateral':['Yes','No','Yes','No','No','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','Yes','No','Yes','No','No','No','Yes','Yes','No','No','No'],
    'Client Number':[23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44],
    'Total Debt':[100,240,200,1000,50,20,345,10,600,40,50,20,100,30,100,600,200,200,150,700,50,120]}

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df_out = df2.rename('Prob').reset_index().merge(df3, on=['City', 'Card', 'Colateral'])
df_out['lower'] = [x.left for x in df_out['DebtPaid']]
df_out['upper'] = [x.right for x in df_out['DebtPaid']]

df_out['l_partial'] = df_out[['lower', 'Prob', 'Total Debt']].prod(axis=1)
df_out['u_partial'] = df_out[['upper', 'Prob', 'Total Debt']].prod(axis=1)

df_out.groupby('Client Number')[['l_partial', 'u_partial']]\
     .agg(lower_price=('l_partial', 'sum'),
          upper_price=('u_partial', 'sum')).clip(0,np.inf)
```

The problem is, that if a client is from Tokyo, has Visa and no collateral, it just doesn't Show up since there aren't statistics for that particular kind of client.

To solve this issue, if the client doesn't have all the statistics, it would calculate with the branch before that.
Ex: If a client is from Tokyo, have visa and No collateral , since we don't have that info, we will calculate with Tokyo->Visa statistics

Any Idea ?